# Google chart not displayed through ajax call

Tags: ajax, charts

I am trying to use [Gooogle Chart Tools](https://www.drupal.org/project/google_chart_tools) for showing some statistics. Below is the example code I'm using:

```
$settings['chart']['chartOne'] = array(
    'header' => array('Apple', 'Banana', 'Mango'),
    'rows' => array(array(12, 6, 8)),
    'columns' => array('Fruit count'),
    'chartType' => 'PieChart',
    'containerId' =>  'content',
    'options' => array(
      'forceIFrame' => FALSE,
      'title' => 'Fruit count',
      'width' => 800,
      'height' => 400
    )
  );
  //Draw it.
  $ret = draw_chart($settings);
  $stats = '<div class="response_stat"><b>'.$ret.'</b></div>';
```

I am then trying to push $stats to page by ajax.

But all I see in display is 'array'.

I feel I need to render the `$ret` array , or maybe there is some other problem. Any idea where the problem is and how to correct it?

Answer (score -1):

This question seems similar to what is described in the issue about Ajax load of chart (current status = needs review).

You may want to try the patch attached to either comment [#3](https://www.drupal.org/node/1613258#comment-6953012) or [#11](https://www.drupal.org/node/1613258#comment-9304781) of that issue.